# Pytorch dataset when the size of the dataset is unknown

Tags: pytorch, dataset

I need a custom PyTorch Dataset that generates training images as following. Get an image from a training set. Choose a random location to crop a 352x352 segment of an image. Compute the usefulness score: the score increases if the segment contains a lot of `class_A` pixels and decreases the more times segment pixels were selected. Return the segment if the score is above a certain threshold and update the counter of selected pixels. If the selected segment has a value below the threshold try another segment. If four consecutive segments scored below the threshold (the image does not have `class_A` pixels or `class_A` pixels appeared on several segments), then go to next image and repeat the procedure. Epoch ends when all images were processed.

Due to the randomness of the selection process I cannot provide `__len__` method or `__getitem__` method.

How should I override these methods, so that I can use my custom `Dataset` class?

Comment: If you can produce something, you can absolutely create `__getitem__`. If the `index` doesn't matter then just don't use it.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen What about the `__len__`? Should I also make a dummy function and just not use it?

Comment: Just have it return something very big.

Comment: Or maybe a number that you consider enough to be an "epoch". For optimizer's schedule or validation